# How to write clipboard+=unnamedplus in a lua config?

Tags: neovim, vimscript-lua

I'm wondering how could i write the settings:

```
set clipboard+=unnamedplus
```

in a lua config.

Currently i do this:

```lua
vim.cmd("set clipboard+=unnamedplus")
```

but is there a way to use:

```lua
vim.opt.clipboard
```

for this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems, i can just write

```
vim.opt.clipboard="unnamedplus"
```

or even

```
vim.opt.clipboard="unnamed,unnamedplus"
```

Over [at stackoverflow they mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691466/what-is-difference-between-vims-clipboard-unnamed-and-unnamedplus-settings):

```
vim.opt.clipboard:append { 'unnamed', 'unnamedplus' }
```

to append values.